# google recaptcha v3 restore keys

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha-v3

I did something very stupid. In my dashboard on the google recaptcha website I deleted the keys for the wrong website.

Now I can not even login to the admin panel on my Wordpress site anymore to disable recaptcha, because the captcha gives an error when logging in.

Is there a workaround to get logged in to the admin panel so I can disable recaptcha?
Or can I restore my recaptcha-keys in the dashboard somehow?

I can not find either solutions on google.

I can access the files on the FTP server to maybe disable recaptcha in the code somehow? But I can't find the right file.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I tried renaming the wordfence-plugin folder as suggested here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-login-to-website-with-captcha/ but without any success :(

Comment: Have you tried rename the recaptcha plugin folder and then try to login to the admin panel? Or uninstall it and install again...

Comment: there is no recaptcha plugin folder in my '/wp-content/plugins' folder, which is strange, no?
I already tried to rename the whole plugins to 'plugins_deactive' to disable all plugins, but even after that I was not able to login.

Comment: Instead of rename, try to move all plugins to another folder outside plugins folder, and try to login (leave plugin folder empty)

Comment: no luck either :(

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the error you get when try to login?

Comment: https://ibb.co/pjVGWBs
the error is in dutch, it just says: "Captcha-code error, try again."

Comment: Try to inspecting your browser console to see if there is some javascript error causing conflict

Comment: I found out that I was still logged in to the admin panel on my phone browser, so I quickly made new recaptcha keys in my google dashboard and put them into WP and now I can login again! Very lucky!

I have no idea how I would have solved this without luck, because I tried 25 different solutions from googling and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Cpanel, you can drop down to the "Softalicious" section which will list your WP installations. It also has a login button to take you directly into the admin section. (I installed Cloudflare's Turnstyle. If if finds an error, it says "Veify you are human" ... but provides no method to do just that! So I too had t log in via this backdoor method!)